# Error: values property should be an object effector-next

Tags: server, next.js, server-side-rendering, effector

When I try to wrap the nextjs application in effector-next I get this error when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It was necessary to add the `_document.tsx` file to the pages folder with this content `import Document from "next/document"`;

```
import { withFork } from "effector-next";

const enhance = withFork({ debug: false });

export default enhance(Document);
```